# UCHAR to Qstring in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function in QT C++ :

```
UCHAR GetResult(HANDLE Handle, UCHAR *Address, UCHAR *Status, int *Value)
{
    UCHAR RxBuffer[9], Checksum;
    DWORD Errors, BytesRead;
    COMSTAT ComStat;
    int i;

    //Check if enough bytes can be read
    ClearCommError(Handle, &Errors, &ComStat);
    if(ComStat.cbInQue>8)
    {
        //Receive
        ReadFile(Handle, RxBuffer, 9, &BytesRead, NULL);

        Checksum=0;
        for(i=0; i<8; i++)
            Checksum+=RxBuffer[i];

        if(Checksum!=RxBuffer[8]) return TMCL_RESULT_CHECKSUM_ERROR;

        *Address=RxBuffer[0];
        *Status=RxBuffer[2];
        *Value=(RxBuffer[4] << 24) | (RxBuffer[5] << 16) | (RxBuffer[6] << 8) | RxBuffer[7];
    } else return TMCL_RESULT_NOT_READY;

    return TMCL_RESULT_OK;
}
```

It returns `UCHAR` values of either:

- `TMCL_RESULT_CHECKSUM_ERROR`
- `TMCL_RESULT_NOT_READY`
- `TMCL_RESULT_OK`

based on the input parameters. I want to now display the return in a `QLabel`, but of course the problem is these are `UCHAR` and not string variables.

How can I convert these values to a `QString` so I can output them.

I thought of doing three if statements but think there is a better way. EG:

```
if (GetResult(RS232Handle, &Address, &Status, &Value)==TMCL_RESULT_OK) {
    printf("TMCL_RESULT_OK");
}
```

Comment: You could make a map, hashmap, or hashtable where the keys are the UCHAR return codes and the values are string representations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `GetResult` is neither Qt nor C++. It is C code. It would probably compile using any 32bit Windows C compiler around 1993.

If you wanted to modernize it, you could use `QSerialPort`:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/serial-controller-40754585
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtSerialPort>

class MyController : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  enum IoStatus { Closed, NotReady, Ok, ChecksumError, PortError, Invalid = -1 };
private:
  QSerialPort m_port{this};
  QDataStream m_str{&m_port};
  IoStatus m_ioStatus = Invalid;
  uint8_t m_address, m_status;
  uint32_t m_value;

  bool check(const QByteArray &packet) {
    char checksum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < packet.size()-1; ++i)
      checksum += packet [i];
    return checksum == packet[packet.size()-1];
  }
  void onError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError err) {
    if (err != QSerialPort::NoError)
      setIoStatus(PortError);
  }
  void onRxData() {
    if (m_port.bytesAvailable() < 9) return;
    if (m_port.error() != QSerialPort::NoError)
      return;
    if (! check(m_port.peek(9)))
      return setIoStatus(ChecksumError);
    uint8_t dummy;
    m_str >> m_address >> dummy >> m_status >> dummy >> m_value;
    setIoStatus(Ok);
  }
  void setIoStatus(IoStatus ioStatus) {
    if (m_ioStatus == ioStatus) return;
    m_ioStatus = ioStatus;
    emit ioStatusChanged(m_ioStatus);
  }
  static QString text(IoStatus ioStatus) {
    switch (ioStatus) {
    case NotReady: return "Not Ready";
    case Ok: return "Ok";
    case ChecksumError: return "Checksum Error";
    case PortError: return "Serial Port Error";
    default: return "Unknown Status";
    }
  }
public:
  explicit MyController(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {
    connect(&m_port, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &MyController::onRxData);
    connect(&m_port, static_cast<void(QSerialPort::*)(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)>(&QSerialPort::error), this, &MyController::onError);
    m_str.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, [this]{ setIoStatus(Closed); });
  }
  bool open() {
    auto rc = m_port.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    if (rc) setIoStatus(NotReady);
    return rc;
  }
  IoStatus ioStatus() const { return m_ioStatus; }
  QString ioStatusText() const { return text(m_ioStatus); }
  Q_SIGNAL void ioStatusChanged(IoStatus);
  QSerialPort *port() { return &m_port; }
};
```

It could be used approximately as follows - this is just an example of how you could interface with the controller:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app{argc, argv};
  MyController ctl;

  QWidget w;
  QFormLayout layout{&w};
  QLineEdit port;
  QLabel status;
  QPushButton open{"Open"};
  layout.addRow("Port", &port);
  layout.addRow(&status);
  layout.addRow(&open);

  QObject::connect(&open, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]{
    ctl.port()->setPortName(port.text());
    ctl.open();
  });
  QObject::connect(&ctl, &MyController::ioStatusChanged, [&]{
    status.setText(ctl.ioStatusText());
  });
  w.show();
  return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

If you insist on using your old C code, it can be modernized just a little bit by returning the result in a structure:

```
struct Result {
  uint8_t address;
  uint8_t status;
  uint32_t value;
  enum Status { Ok, NotReady, ChecksumError, ReadError };
  Status ioStatus = Ok;

  QString ioStatusText() const {
    switch (ioStatus) {
    case NotReady: return "Not Ready";
    case Ok: return "Ok";
    case ChecksumError: return "Checksum Error";
    case ReadError: return "Read Error";
    default: return "Unknown Status";
    }
  }
};

Result getResult(HANDLE handle)
{
  Result result;

  DWORD errors, bytesRead;
  COMSTAT comStat;

  ClearCommError(handle, &errors, &comStat);
  if (comStat.cbInQue < 9) {
    result.ioStatus = Result::NotReady;
    return result;
  }

  uint8_t buffer[9];
  ReadFile(handle, buffer, 9, &bytesRead, NULL);

  if (bytesRead < 9) {
    result.ioStatus = Result::ReadError;
    return result;
  }

  uint8_t checksum=0;
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    checksum += buffer[i];

  if (checksum != buffer[8]) {
    result.ioStatus = Result::ChecksumError;
    return result;
  }

  result.address = buffer[0];
  result.status = buffer[2];
  result.value = (buffer[4] << 24) | (buffer[5] << 16) | (buffer[6] << 8) | buffer[7];
  return result;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
auto result = getResult(handle);
printf("%s\n", result.ioStatusText().toLocal8Bit().constData());
```

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by function *GetResult()* is simply a uchar value, NOT a pointer to a container of uchars.

So, if I understand your question, I think fastest way (according informations you have provided) is to do this in your Qt project:

```
QString text_to_display;

uchar result = GetResult(RS232Handle, &Address, &Status, &Value);

switch(result)
{
    case TMCL_RESULT_OK:
         text_to_display = "TMC_RESULT_OK";
         break;

    case TMCL_RESULT_NOT_READY:
         text_to_display = "TMCL_RESULT_NOT_READY";
         break;

    case TMCL_RESULT_CHECKSUM_ERROR:
         text_to_display = "TMCL_RESULT_CHECKSUM_ERROR";
         break;

    default:
         break;
}

QLabel *label_to_show_result = new QLabel(text_to_display, this);
```

This doesn't change your *GeResult* function, simply takes its result and display a text in a QLabel according to it.

Of course you can use other way, such as *QHash* to map couples of result-text, avoiding switch case structure.

Comment: Ya, similar to my if statement solution.